# Replace some text strings in a file

Tags: xml, bash

I have a bunch of files that have the following entires in them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE config SYSTEM "/usr/share/xml/config/dtd/parameter.conf.xml.dtd">
<!--
See parameter.conf(5) for a description.
-->

<parameter>
    <debug enable="0" />

    <share>/bin/true</unshare>

    <shroptions require="nosuid,nodev" />

    <mksharepoint enable="1" remove="false" />

    <volume fstype="nfs" server="MEDIA-HOME-LAX.IT.DISNEY.COM" path="%(USER)" sharepoint="/home/%(USER)" sgrp="domain users" />
</parameter>
```

I want to replace a few strings in the `<volume ...` line and insert something near the end of the line from:

```
<volume fstype="nfs" server="MEDIA-HOME-LAX.IT.DISNEY.COM" path="%(USER)" sharepoint="/home/%(USER)" sgrp="domain users" />
```

to this:

```
<volume fstype="cifs" server="MEDIA-HOME-LAX.IT.DISNEY.COM" path="HOME" sharepoint="/home/%(USER)" sgrp="domain users" options="vers=3.0" />
```

What would be the best way to achieve this? I have approx. 1200 of these config files that I'd like to make changes to.

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to the forum. All I want to do is 1) to replace the value of fstype if it's nfs to cifs, 2) replace the value of path where is it currently %(USER) with HOME, and at the end of the <volume line before the /> insert options="vers=3.0"

Comment: Hope that makes my question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try: `find DIRECTORY | xargs sed -i  's/ORIGINAL/REPLACEMENT/g'`

Where `ORIGINAL` is the string you're trying to replace, `REPLACEMENT` is the replacement string, and `DIRECTORY` is the folder in which all your files are contained.

This can be applied directly in cases 1 and 2, where you want to replace one string with another.

In case 3, since you want to append a string to a line that contains `<volume`, you can use the sed command with capture groups, which save a part of your string to be used in the `REPLACEMENT` part.

General example of the regex:

```
's/(KEEP)NOKEEP/\1REPLACEMENT/g'
```

where `KEEP` is the part of your pattern that you want to save and use in `\1`, NOKEEP is the part of your matching pattern that you want to match on, but don't want to save, and `REPLACEMENT` is any replacement string that you want.

In this case, the regex for your case 3 would look like

```
's/(<volume.*)>$/\1options="vers=3.0">/g'
```

where \1 in the replacement part expands to become the line you captured, minus the last angle bracket.

In order to use capture groups, you may need to use extended regex with sed, which means you have to add an additional `-E` or `-r` flag to your sed command:

```
sed -ir 's/(<volume.*)>$/\1options="vers=3.0">/g'
```

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: Thanks Carol for sharing your suggestion, your suggestion solves 1st and 2nd part of my problem, which was, 1) to replace the value of fstype if it's nfs to cifs, 2) replace the value of path where is it currently %(USER) with HOME. I'm trying to use your solution to solve the last part of my problem, which is to insert options="vers=3.0" before the end of the <volume line. I manage to test it by using; grep "<volume" FILE | sed 's/\/>/options="vers=3.0" \/>/g' and that worked only on the screen by I'd like to make the change in the file not just on screen with grep.

Comment: You can capture the entire <volume line using the following regex: `(<volume.*)>$`, where the parentheses denote a capture group (it's like you saved this part of the string) and the dollar sign is the end of the line, so you capture the entire line except for the last angle bracket at the end of the line. You can then use the capture group by putting `\1 options="vers...` in the REPLACEMENT part of sed command, where `\1` spits out the string you saved using the capture group. I've amended my answer to include the bit with capture groups.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Carol, I tried your suggestion but I got a sed error. The command I used is;

find FILE | xargs sed -i 's/(<volume.*)>$/\1options="vers=3.0">/g'

and it returned;

sed: -e expression #1, char 39: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Appreciate any suggestion you may have.

Comment: Depending on what shell you're running, you might need to add an extra -E for extended regex right after sed, or a -r, so your full command would be:
`find FILE | xargs sed -iE 's/(<volume.*)>$/\1options="vers=3.0">/g'` or `find FILE | xargs sed -ir 's/(<volume.*)>$/\1options="vers=3.0">/g' `.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it (if valid XML) is to use [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), for example in your case to replace `fstype` and `path` this could work:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '/parameter/volume[@fstype]/@fstype' -v cifs \
    -u '/parameter/volume[@path]/@path' -v HOME file.xml
```